# ExecStop doesn't work in service

Tags: linux, raspberry-pi, archlinux, systemd

I was implementing basic blinking of LED on raspberry pi. Basically my idea is when i run a timer, the pi starts to blink and when I stop the timer, pi deactivate automatically. I have three bash scripts(activate.sh, deactivate.sh, toggle.sh).

**1.toggle.timer**

```
[Unit]
Description="toggle timer
Requires= activate.service
After= activate.service

[Timer] 
OnActiveSec=0.5
OnUnitActiveSec=500ms

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

**2.toggle.service**

```
# toggle.service companion to toggle.timer
[Unit]
Description = LED Toggle Service Unit
Requires = activate.service
After = activate.service

[Service]
Type = oneshot
ExecStart = /usr/local/bin/toggle.sh
StartLimitIntervals=10s
StartLimitBurst=30

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
3. activate.service
[Unit]
Description=LED activate service
StopWhenUnneeded=true


[Service]
Type=oneshot
RemainAfterExit= yes

ExecStart= /usr/local/bin/activate.sh
ExecStop= /usr/local/bin/deactivate.sh


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

I have tested my three scripts and they all work fine.
However, when I do systemctl start toggle.timer, toggle service starts and everything works good. When I stop, the toggle doesn't stop and the activate.service doesn't run my ExecStop script. I have no idea what's wrong with it.

Comment: A query - When you say you stop the toggle, is that the timer ? (looks like as the service you have is `oneshot`)

Comment: yes. When I stop toggle.timer, toggle service shut down automatically. I figured it out because I added the [install] part in my service file, it shouldn't be wanted-by-multi-user. I still a bit confused by this [install] part in arch linux. However, after I delete this part, it works.